# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, ienumerable, casting, sqldatareader, idatareader

I've been trying to understand why it's giving me this error because I'm not using SqlDataReader, I get that I'm using SQL Server and the Interface is returning the specific type but still I'm telling .NET to use IDataReader instead.

Here's the code:

```
    public DataSet ExecuteSelectProcedure(string procedure, List<Parameter> parameters)
    {
        conexion.Open();

        try
        {
            IDbCommand command = conexion.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Connection = conexion;
            command.CommandText = procedure;

            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                IDbDataParameter dataParameter = command.CreateParameter();
                dataParameter.Direction = (System.Data.ParameterDirection) parameter.Direction;
                dataParameter.Value = parameter.Value;
                dataParameter.ParameterName = parameter.Name;
                dataParameter.DbType = (DbType) parameter.Type;
                command.Parameters.Add(dataParameter);
            }


            IDataReader result = command.ExecuteReader();
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            foreach (var table in (IEnumerable<IDataReader>) result)
            {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.Load(table);
                dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
            }

            result.Close();

            return dataSet;
        }
        finally
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }
```

The error is when casting IEnumerable on the foreach loop. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* using `SqlDataReader`, because that's the actual type that `command.ExecuteReader` is returning. You're then trying to cast that to an `IEnumerable<IDataReader>`, but it's not clear why. Why did you *expect* that to work?

You iterate over multiple tables (etc) in an `IDataReader` by calling [`NextResult()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult.aspx). For example:

```
do
{
    // Read the current result; if reading manually, call Read()
    // to get to the next row within the result
} while (reader.NextResult());
```

Comment: The foreach loop was originally this                 do
                {
                    var dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataTable.Load(result);
                    dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
                    if (result.IsClosed)
                        break;
                } while (result.NextResult());

Comment: @Victor: Well then I suggest you go back to that :)

Comment: The problem is that, for example, when the result has 3 tables the dataset is returning with table 1 and 3... Sorry for my english here, not my first language... :-D

Comment: @Victor: That suggests you're calling `NextResult()` twice instead of once.

Comment: Ok, I replace NextResult() with Read() and the DataSet returns the correct set of tables...

Thanks...

Comment: @Victor: You shouldn't need to call Read at all - DataTable.Load will be doing that. I suspect you had two calls to NextResult though. Without seeing your code, it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: @Victor: Ah, I hadn't seen the code in your comment. That certainly *looks* okay... unless DataTable.Load calls NextResult, of course...